# Modify sort-relevant parts of an element in a C++ std::set

Tags: c++, set, std

I know this is problematic, but I am curious whether doing this causes undefined behavior?

```
class A
{
public:
    int i;
};
class As {
public:
    bool operator()(const A* l, const A* r)
    {
        return l->i < r->i;
    }
};
int main() {
    std::set<A*,As> s;
    A* a1 = new A();
    a1->i = 9;
    A* a2 = new A();
    a2->i = 2;
    s.insert(a1);
    s.insert(a2);
    for(std::set<A*,As>::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
        std::cout<<(*i)->i<<std::endl;
    for(std::set<A*,As>::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
    {
        if((*i)->i == 2)
            (*i)->i = 22;
    }
    for(std::set<A*,As>::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
        std::cout<<(*i)->i<<std::endl;
    //now s is in incorrect state, insert all elements into a tmp one
    std::set<A*,As> t;
    for(std::set<A*,As>::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
        t.insert(*i);
    s.swap(t);
    for(std::set<A*,As>::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
        std::cout<<(*i)->i<<std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
2
9
22
9
9
22
```

It seems to work fine when compiled by GCC 4.7, but I don't know whether this may just be luck.

Comment: That is almost certainly undefined behaviour. You have changed the ordering conditions for the elements of the set.

Comment: yes I know this is bad, however, only from the example, it seems acceptable. The only operation on "broken set" is ++iterator and that was determined after the last insert operation.

Comment: If it is undefined behaviour, then you can't rely on anything working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Standard (C++11) says about the key comparison function used in associative containers, i.e. containers like `std::set`:

> (§23.2.4/3) [...] For any two keys `k1` and `k2` in the same container, calling `comp(k1,k2)` shall always return the same value.

There `comp` refers to the comparison function, which in your case is the functor `As()`.

Clearly, when the keys contain pointers to external objects and the result of calling `comp(k1,k2)` depends on those external objects, then modifying the objects causes the rule above to be violated.

The Standard doesn't say what happens if you violate this rule. So, formally speaking, you have undefined behaviour then (because the Standard leaves the behaviour undefined).

In practice, I guess there is a significant chance that terrible things, including segmentation faults, could happen as a result of a violation, because the next time the set is searched for a key, or an insert is made, the search algorithm – built on the assumption that the keys are in order – might go astray and make out-of-bounds accesses and the like.

So the conclusion is that, yes, this is UB, and can cause bad things to happen even if it works in a few selected cases in practice.